# EXC_BAD_ACCESS thrown with two tables in one view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a view with two tables. I handle each of these tables with two different controllers instead of file's owner. The app loads up correctly, but when I scroll the "Under Featured" / Store table, a EXC_BAD_ACCESS is thrown. It seems the table isn't retain. I've been reading the web up and down, but am unable to find the cause.

**xib:**
[image]

**UnderFeaturedViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "iMagsAppDelegate.h"

@interface UnderFeaturedViewController : UIViewController <UITabBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *showTableView;
    IBOutlet UITabBarItem *hotButton;
    IBOutlet UITabBarItem *allButton;
    IBOutlet UITabBarItem *catButton;
    UIPopoverController *popoverController;
    NSMutableArray *showArray;
    iMagsAppDelegate *appDelegate;
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *showTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarItem *hotButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarItem *allButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarItem *catButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *showArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) iMagsAppDelegate *appDelegate;

-(void) setTitle:(NSString *)title;
-(void) setGuest;
-(void) updateView:(NSNotification *)notification;
-(void) dismissModalView:(int) modalID;
-(Boolean) isGuest;

-(IBAction) showTag:(NSString*)tag;
-(IBAction) showName:(NSString *) name;
-(IBAction) showStore;
-(IBAction) showOwned;
-(IBAction) showCategories;
-(IBAction) showSearch;
-(IBAction) showMore;
-(IBAction) showFirstDialog;

@end
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSInteger section = [indexPath row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", section];

    return cell;
}
```

**Zombies:**

[image]

**Backtrace:**

```
#0  0x0182509b in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x005afd18 in -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _scrollViewWillBeginDragging] ()
#2  0x005a31e9 in -[UIScrollView _updatePanGesture] ()
#3  0x005a74e6 in -[UIScrollView handlePan:] ()
#4  0x0081be39 in _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions ()
#5  0x0081b143 in -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] ()
#6  0x0081c3cf in -[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] ()
#7  0x0081ea31 in ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke_0541 ()
#8  0x0081e98c in _UIGestureRecognizerApplyBlocksToArray ()
#9  0x008173e7 in _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate ()
#10 0x0057f812 in -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] ()
#11 0x0057fba2 in -[UIWindow sendEvent:] ()
#12 0x00566384 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#13 0x00559aa9 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#14 0x017f5fa9 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#15 0x016361c5 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#16 0x0159b022 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#17 0x0159990a in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#18 0x01598db4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#19 0x01598ccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#20 0x017f4879 in GSEventRunModal ()
#21 0x017f493e in GSEventRun ()
#22 0x00557a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#23 0x00001e5d in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff5f0) at ...
```

Comment: It actually works when commenting out super dealloc. What does this mean? -(void)dealloc { //[super dealloc]; }

Comment: looks like your controller get deallocated but scroll view still have it as the delegate. where do you retain the controller?

Comment: if you don't call `[super dealloc]` than it will never get deallocated so it is not a zombie anymore

Comment: Thanks for you answers! Answer to where I retain the controller; I've got it set up this way: 1. MainWindow.xib which has appDelegate, Window, Tab Bar Controller which has a Tab Bar and a Navigation Controller which has a SplitViewController, [like this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62903/Skjermbilde%202012-01-06%20kl.%2012.13.48.png). 2. The SplitViewController uses the NIB-file TableViewWithFeatured which [looks like this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62903/Skjermbilde%202012-01-06%20kl.%2012.15.27.png). 3.In SplitViewController.h I add the @property (nonatomic, retain) UIView and UnderFe.. and Feat..

Comment: I didn't really solve this, but I found a solution to how to have two tables in one window (This is without one controller for each table):

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(tableView != [self tableView1]){
      //do stuff
    }
    //handle tableView2
    else{

    }
    }

Answer (score 0):

So SplitViewController is the file's owner which retain the view but not UnderFeaturedViewController

Create an strong/retain reference IBOutlet for the UnderFeaturedViewController so SplitViewController does retain it.

I think the problem is that UnderFeaturedViewController did not get retain at anywhere so it get deallocated at next run loop.

You also can set a break point on `dealloc` so you know when does it get deallocated.